# How to use "toHaveBeenCalledAfter" with a function that has been called several times?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I have a function:

```
funtion foo() {
  Spinner.setVisible(true);
  await ApiService.doApiCall();
  Spinner.setVisible(false);
}
```

I'd like to unit test the order of function calls, to make sure the spinner is being shown before the API call and hidden afterwards.

I use Jest. I tried this:

```
import 'jest-extended';

describe('foo', () => {
  it('should make spinner visible before the api call', async () => {
    const setVisibleSpy = jest.spyOn(Spinner, 'setVisible').mockImplementation(() => true);
    const doApiCallSpy = jest.spyOn(ApiService, 'doApiCall').mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve(true));
    expect(setVisibleSpy).toHaveBeenCalledBefore(doApiCallSpy ); // <-- THIS WORKS!!!
  })

  it('should make spinner hidden afterthe api call', async () => {
    const setVisibleSpy = jest.spyOn(Spinner, 'setVisible').mockImplementation(() => true);
    const doApiCallSpy = jest.spyOn(ApiService, 'doApiCall').mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve(true));
    expect(setVisibleSpy).toHaveBeenCalledAfter(doApiCallSpy ); // <-- THIS DOESN'T WORK!!!
  })
})
```

As I understand, the check after doesn't work, because the very first call of the `setVisible()` function actually happen before the `doApiCall()`.

How can I check that the *second* call of the `setVisible()` function happened after the `doApiCall()` call?

Comment: Control when the promise resolves using the deferred pattern. That way you can assert that it was _last_ called with true before resolving and with false after resolving.

Comment: I thought about that, but feels a bit hacky. I expected something like accessing call order or maybe to check if `setVisibility` function was called with certain params alongside with the order check

Comment: You could write your own toHaveBeenNthCalledBefore/After matchers, based on the existing examples, or just assert on the mock properties they use (see links from e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/46066250/3001761).